# Why does this code display incorrect Unicode?

Tags: javascript, unicode

The following minimal code creates a string containing a dog emoji and red heart emoji. It then paws through the string, showing the second emoji, the red heart. Why is a black heart shown (on Firefox) instead?

```
var u='\ud83d\udc0e\u2764';
var count=0;
for (let point of u)
    if (count++)
        alert(u+": "+point);
```

Comment: FYI, `\ud83d\udc0e` is codepoint U+1F40E, which is a horse.  A dog would be U+1F415 (`\ud83d\udc15`) or U+1F436 (`\ud83d\udc36`) instead.

Answer (score 4):

`U+2764 HEAVY BLACK HEART` predates color emojis, and so it is a black heart when treated by itself.  To make it red, join it with `U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16`, eg:

```
var u='\ud83d\udc0e\u2764\ufe0f';
```

However, your `for` loop would ignore the `\ufe0f` and still just display `\u2764` by itself, since they are separate codepoints.

Tweak your loop to peek the next codepoint after `u` and include it if it is a variable selector:

```
alert("\u2764"); // black heart
alert("\u2764\ufe0f"); // red heart
```

Comment: It's interesting that both your answer and original OPs code show a red heart to me (google chrome on linux). And they both return a black hear on firefox (linux as well)

Comment: On my Firefox on Windows, `alert("\u2764")` shows a black heart, but `alert("\u2764\ufe0f")` shows a red heart

Comment: https://codepoints.net/U+FE0F ('colorful'). Wow. Unicode started off as a simple translation from 16-bit values to characters in various languages. Now it is almost a programming language, like PostScript for rendering, which derived from Forth. While I can see the motivation for (for example) including both accented characters and separate accent glyphs, it creates the need for String.normalize and very long regular expressions to recognize all the Unicode graphemes, and even this cannot be done completely. There must be a better way to design the Web other than HTML/CSS/JS and this!